# Identify rows where certain colmns are null or empty

Tags: sql

I have a table where i should validate certain columns. I would like to know if we can write one query that gives all such records instead of validating each column separately.

Lets say i have this table.

```
id |  x  |  y  | z  
----+-----+-----+----
  1 | null| 200 | 
  2 | 100 |     | 42
  3 |  45 | 100 | 1 
  4 |     |     | 2
```

I would like to return validation messages for all the rows in a table. There will be few column that should not be validated. Lets say i don't want 'Z' to be validated

The query should return the following

```
row    |  error message
-------+---------------
1      |  Column(s) 'X' should not be null or empty
2      |  Column(s) 'Y' should not be null or empty
4      |  Column(s) 'X', 'Y' should not be null or empty
```

Comment: Add a few more rows of sample data, and also the expected result. And show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean somthing like this?

```
select row_number() over (order by id) as row,
       'Column(s) ' + 
        stuff(case when isnull(x,'') = '' then ', ''X''' else '' end +
              case when isnull(y,'') = '' then ', ''Y''' else '' end +
              case when isnull(z,'') = '' then ', ''Z''' else '' end,1,2,'') +
       ' should not be null or empty' as [error message]
from table_name
where isnull(x,'') = '' 
   or isnull(y,'') = '' 
   or isnull(z,'') = ''
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: the question about regular MSSQL, No?

Comment: The <sql> tag is for ANSI/ISO SQL, i..e. the international standard. Use <sql-server> tag for MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the invalid records with one query.

`select * from table_name where x = null or y = null or z = null;`

I feel weird writing this query because if I was making the table, I wouldn't make it possible to insert bad data in the first place. Relational databases come with the power to do just that. You could make it impossible to insert null data into each column by putting a `NOT NULL` constraint on columns that should not be null. Here is an example.

```
  create table table_name (
    id   serial primary key not null,
    x    text not null,
    y    text not null,
    z    text not null
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CTE` with `APPLY` operator to check column `NULL` values and display them as separate result rest

```
with cte as
(
    select a.* from table t
    cross apply (
       values (id, 'x', x), (id, 'y',  y), (id, 'z', z)
    )a(id, names, value)
    where a.value is null
)

select id,
       columns = concat('Column(s) ', stuff(
                     (select ','+names from cte where id = c.id for xml path('')),
                       1,1,''),  ' should not be null or empty')
from cte c
group by id
```

Note: `APPLY` operator is available for SQL Server